# how to type switch case based on function or function parameters?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function that returns an input element with its corresponding properties based on the function that receives to use on the onChange event. this function is received in the component props. the problem is that i couldn't type the cases of when the function receives a ChangeEvent for a HTMLInputElement, HTMLSelectElement or HTMLTextareaElement.

```
type OptionsProps = {
    description: string;
    value: string;
};

type SelectProps = {
    handleChange: ({ target }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void;
    value: string;
    options: OptionsProps;
};

type TextareaProps = {
    handleChange: ({ target }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void;
    cols?: number;
    rows?: number;
};

type InputProps = {
    handleChange: ({ target }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
} & (InputNumberProps | InputTextProps | InputFileProps);

type Props = {
    title: string;
    name: string;
    htmlFor: string;
} & (InputProps | TextareaProps | SelectProps);

export const ModalFormDivider = (props: Props) => {
    const { title, name, htmlFor, handleChange} = props;

    const determineElement = () => {
        switch (handleChange) {
            case (({ target }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void): {...Do something}
case (({ target }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextareaElement>) => void): {...Do other thing}
case (({ target }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void): {...Do whatever}
        }
    };
}
```

i tried putting the type that the editor says handleChange is (({ target }: React.ChangeEvent) => void) for example) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First let's look at the definition of a switch statement.

```
switch (expression_or_value) {
  case comparison_expression_or_value1:
    statements
  case comparison_expression_or_value2:
    statements
  // …
  case comparison_expression_or_valueN:
    statements
  default:
    statements
}
```

`switch` statements evaluate an `expression/value`, then compare the result of that evaluation to the `expression/value` of the `case` clause. The code block for whichever `case` clause matches the initial `expression/value` will end up being your result.

In your example, you are passing a `type` as the `case` value, which won't work as a type is not a valid `expression/value`

Here is an breakdown of what you are doing:

```
type FNType1 = ({ target }: { target: Record<string, any> }) => void
type FNType2 = ({ target }: { target: Record<string, any> }) => void

const fn: FNType1 = ({ target }) => {}
const fn2: FNType2 = ({ target }) => {}

const checkFnType = (f: Function) => {
  switch (typeof f) {
    case FNType1:
      console.log('x')
      break; 

    case FNType2:
      console.log('x2')
      break; 
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

This should actually throw an error in your IDE like:

```
'FNType1' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

If you really wanted to, you could compare functions in a switch statement, but that would require the function call signatures to be different.

```
type FNType1 = ({ target }: { target: Record<string, any> }) => void
type FNType2 = ({ target }: { target: Record<string, any> }) => void

const fn: FNType1 = ({ target }) => {}
const fn2: FNType2 = ({ target }) => {}

const checkFn = (f: Function) => {
  switch (f) {
    case fn:
      console.log('function 1')
      break;
    
    case fn2:
      console.log('function 2')
      break;  
    default:
      break;
  }
}

checkFn(fn); // function 1
checkFn(fn2); // function 2
```

I think what you really want to do is use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) which will help you correctly type your `handleChange` function in your `ModalFormDivider` component usage. You would also want to add a `type` prop for picking which element you want to return. This is more in line with what (I think) you are trying to do.

```
type AdditionalProps<T> = T extends HTMLTextAreaElement
  ? TextAreaProps
  : T extends HTMLSelectElement
  ? SelectProps
  : T extends HTMLInputElement
  ? InputProps
  : {};

interface ModalFormDividerProps<T> {
  title: string;
  name: string;
  htmlFor: string;
  type: "select" | "input" | "textarea";
  handleChange: (args: React.ChangeEvent<T>) => void;
}
```

```
const ModalFormDivider = <T extends Record<string, any>>({
  title,
  name,
  htmlFor,
  handleChange,
  type,
  ...rest
}: ModalFormDividerProps<T> & AdditionalProps<T>) => {

  console.log(title, name, htmlFor, handleChange, rest);

  switch (type) {
    case "input":
      return <TextField {...rest} />;
    case "select":
      const { value, options } = (rest as unknown) as SelectProps;
      return (
        <Select value={value}>
          {options.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem value={option}>{option}</MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      );
    case "textarea":
      return <TextField {...rest} multiline />;

    default:
      console.error("Unexpected component type", type);
      return null;
  }
};
```

Hope this helps!